# No module named project name.settings

Tags: python

I tried running (python manage.py runserver. But it keeps giving me an error

*I tried changing the directory of my setting but i resulted the same way
*

Comment: Add more details, like project directory structure and `manage.py` file code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your project name with file tree here:

```
-- nameofyourproject\
 |-- __init__.py
 |-- manage.py
 |-- settings.py
```